# Example with ${\rm vol}\ D>\lim_i\ {\rm vol}\ D_i$

Tags: metric-geometry, hausdorff-measure

I have a question about some calculation which is in the paper : Two
counterexamples in low-dimensional length geometry - Burago, Ivanov,
and Shoenthal

I want to say their second result and the calculation is omitted in
the paper

I will say roughly their second result : Note that if $c_n
:[0,1]\rightarrow (X,d)$ is a continuous curve where $X$ is a length
metric space and if $c_n$ goes to $c$ uniformly then we have $${\rm
length} \ c\leq {\rm lim\ inf}_n \ {\rm length}\ c_n\ \ast$$

> But they have a counter example s.t. $2$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $h_2$ does not satisfy property like $\ast$

my answer :

i) Divide $[0,1]^2$ into 9 squares of equal sides so that we delete
five. So we have four squares around vertices of $[0,1]^2$.

If it is denoted as $C_1$, then we do the process repeatedly so that
we define $C:=\bigcap_i\ C_i$ (cf. Cantor Set)

ii) In $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider a closed disks $D_i$ s.t. $D_i
\rightarrow D$ in Gromov-Hausdorff distance, where $D$ is still a
disk.

Assume that $D_i$ has empty intersection with $xy$-plane and $D$ has
$C$ intersection with $xy$-plane.

iii) Assume that $2\varepsilon> {\rm area}\ D_i>\varepsilon$ for all
$i$.

Since $D$ contains $C$, so ${\rm area}\ D\geq \delta +\varepsilon$
for some $\delta > 2\varepsilon$.

Comment: Note unless you assume much more about $C$. For instance, $C$ could have Hausdorff dimension $0$ (or just strictly less than $1$). Then you can have disks $D$ with $h_2(D)$ as close to $h_2(D\cap R^2\times 0)$ as you wish ("spikes" can have arbitrarily small $h_2$). Lastly, please, proofread your question and correct the punctuation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I add more detail.